# SOME documents saved to Sharepoint won't open via the URL/link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, error

So the background is that we have a document library that files get saved to.
When users open the site to access the files, they open up and it is not a problem.

However, when the links to these files are emailed out to be shared with other users, some of the links when clicked cause an error to appear saying: 
**"There has been an error while loading form..."**

The error details says the form template that the user may not have the required permissions to open the file. When I check, the user has the appropriate permissions. Once again, when accessing from SharePoint directly, they open up for the very same user without any problems. Only the link causes this with **SOME** files. Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Can you post an example of the actual document URL and the same document URL shared via mail (certainly asterisk/comment out any confidential pieces)? Is it the same link? if you can't comment, please edit your original question to add more info as asked here.